# Carbon Skip certain month

Tags: laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

Is there a way to skip a certain month? I just need to show January, February, September, October, November and December.

This is my code:

```
$emptyMonth = ['count' => 0, 'month' => 0];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $emptyMonth['month'] = $i;
    $monthlyArray[$i - 1] = $emptyMonth;
}

$data = DB::table('doc')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count,MONTH(created_at) as month'))
    ->where('status', 'done')
    ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse('first day of january'))
    ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::parse('last day of december'))
    ->whereyear('created_at', Carbon::now())
    ->groupBy('month')
    ->orderBy('month')
    ->get()
    ->toarray();

foreach ($data as $key => $array) {
    $monthlyArray[$array->month - 1] = $array;
}

$result = collect($monthlyArray)->pluck('count');
```

Is there a way to skip or not show some of specific of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [whereMonth](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses):

```
  $data = DB::table('doc')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as count,MONTH(created_at) as month'))
            ->where('status', 'done')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse('first day of january'))
            ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::parse('last day of december'))
            ->whereyear('created_at', Carbon::now())
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->whereMonth('created_at',1)
                    ->orWhereMonth('created_at',2)
                    ->orWhereMonth('created_at',9); // extra
            })
            ->groupBy('month')
            ->orderBy('month')
            ->get()
            ->toarray();
```

or simply do it using raw and [Month](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-month-function.php) mysql function:

```
  $query->whereIn(DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)'),[1,2,3,9]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make this filter in the foreach. Assuming you have the month as a number in the database:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $array) {
   if(in_array($array->month, [1,2,9,10,11,12]))
   {
       $monthlyArray[$array->month - 1] = $array;
    }
}
```